# unable to clear jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a Button, on its click i want to clear a data table and reload with fresh data. But when i click on the button the data table is not getting cleared.

i have written the code below but probably the browser is not getting the method dataTable()

i am getting this error: TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

```
function Loaded(result) {
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#myDataTable").dataTable().fnClearTable();
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: dataTables are a jQuery plugin. Have you loaded the dataTable script?

Comment: oh ya. Problem solved btw. I had added two ref of jquery.js files in the page. 
SOLUTION: if u ever face similar problem first check how many jquery files are included into the source file. LOL!!!


Admin plz close the question.

Answer (score 0):

dataTables are a jQuery plugin. Have you loaded the dataTable script?